# ValidateInput(False) not working when using window.location.href to call mvc and gives action dangerous request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 (vb) and I'm stuck at this last part to really finish my search functionality. The ValidateInput(False) parameter works on every single call, except when I'm using a call via javascript. 
The error I get is the following: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
I get this when I'm trying to search on something html-like.

I'll list the code I'm using:

MVC view:

```
<input type="text" id="searchtextMVC" name="query" onkeydown="EnterKeyDownForWhoIsWho(event);" data-url="@Url.Content("~/Controller/")"/>
```

javascript:

```
window.location.href = $('#searchtextMVC').attr('data-url') + 'Index/' + document.getElementById('searchtextMVC').value;
```

these two fix it so I get my correct url with parameter.

My action starts like this:

```
<ValidateInput(False)> _
        Public Function Index() As ActionResult
             Code stuff, eventually using CStr(RouteData.Values("fullName"))
```

Now the problem is the ValidateInput works on every call EXCEPT for the one via javascript.
I have also added requestValidationMode="2.0" to my web.config, but that didn't help. I need to give the parameter fullName for my function to work.

I've spent too much time searching on the internet for no answers, so I hope we can figure this out together.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I also tried requestPathInvalidCharacters="" in my web.config and this made it so that I always got an illegal character error.

EDIT2:

I tried url-encoding in the javascript, but it didn't help. Here's what I tried:

```
searchValue = $('#searchtextMVC').attr('data-url') + 'Index/' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('searchtextMVC').value);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:**

Setting ValidateInput to false will allow "potentially dangerous requests" in the Request.Form.

However, the way you are building your URL, you are getting the inputted value and adding it as a part of the URL. Setting ValidateInput to false would not prevent the  "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected".

**Possible solution:**

You might want to consider URL encoding the entered value and passing it in the querystring.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Encoding the entered value didn't work though. I'm still getting thesame error. I've updated my answer with what I tried.